# pandoc places curly brackets around square brackets

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I would like to use a LaTeX command in a markdown file. In the markdown file I add

```
\mycommand[options]{something}
```

when pandoc renders the markdown file to TeX it becomes

```
\mycommand{[}options{]}{something}
```

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with pandoc 1.17.2:

```
$ echo '\mycommand[options]{something}' | pandoc -t latex

\mycommand[options]{something}
```

Comment: Using the latex code above I get the same results, but please try a more specific latex sequence, such as `\twocolumnn[\section{test}\label{test}]{something}`. The problem appears to be peculiar to `\section`.

Comment: @acspike again, your input works for me with pandoc 1.19.2.1

Comment: I can confirm this. Thierry's latex snippet works in both pandoc 1.17.2 and 1.19.2.1. My latex snippet behaves as described by Thierry in 1.17.2 but works in 1.19.2.1. Thanks @mb21!

Comment: With `pandoc 2.2.3.2`, I find that this exact example works. However, `echo '\Volcite{1}[25]{citekey}' | pandoc -f markdown -t latex` returns `\Volcite{1}{[}25{]}\{citekey\}`. Is there a way to make it return `\Volcite{1}[25]{citekey}`?